# Restrict Site collection admins to view documents in Shared Document Library

Tags: site-collection, administration, library

Is there any way to restrict site collection administrators to view or edit the documents in shared documents library.

If yes, then please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A user specifically given site collection admin access will be able to access anything in the site.

If you want to have someone with more or less site collection admin access to everywhere but the one library, you will need to do the following:

- Remove them as a site collection admin.
- Add them to the root with Full Control access.
- Go to the library and make it stop inheriting permissions from the site .
- Remove the user's Full Control access and give any permission what you intend to have for that user only for that library.